# gitlab rule with `when: manual` is always triggered

Tags: gitlab-ci

Trying to model a job that runs automatically for tags and manually for specific branches using rules. However the job is always triggered without user intervention

```
ismanual:
  stage: prepare
  rules:
    # Always deliver a tagged build
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG != ""'
      when: on_success
    # Manual deliver a feature branch build
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /feature\/.*/'
      when: manual
  script:
    - echo "hello"
```

I'm using gitlab.com!

Comment: what do you mean by always triggered without user intervention? is it triggers without commit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change your check for commit tags. In a rules clause you can check for a variable like below, so no need to compare it to an empty string.

```
ismanual:
  stage: prepare
  rules:
    # Always deliver a tagged build
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
    # Manual deliver a feature branch build
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /feature\/.*/'
      when: manual
  script:
    - echo "hello"
```